# Removing fonts from PDF don't seem to work

Tags: optimization, pdf, filesize

The size of my PDF-files i can see is 90% embedded fonts. However if i try to remove the fonts using the PDF Optimizer in Adobe Acrobat size of the file don't change.

Here is a calculation of the space usage done by Acrobat:

[image]

And if i remove the fonts in the fonts options dialog the size remains the same. Is there anything else that i can do to remove the fonts, or am i doing something wrong?

[image]

BR
Andreas

Comment: Why was this closed? I am actually very interested in this question.